Plotting model-adjusted baseline values of change scores
I know using change scores to evaluate a treatment effect on an outcome in an RCT is frowned upon by some. But I'm interested in knowing what people normally do when it comes to plotting the model-adjusted means in either the case of including baseline in the outcome vector or adjusting for baseline as in an ANCOVA. In the latter case, baseline values of the outcome are not estimated in the model but in the former they are. Given they are change scores and have a value of zero at baseline (in the sample at least), is it reasonable (if not technically valid) to just project the plot back to zero in both treatment arms. A reviewer is questioning why a students model-adjusted means aren't zero at baseline but of course these aren't descriptive means and it depends on what covariates are adjusted for in the model.
22/05/2024 - Including some code to simulate longitudinal data, and two plots - the first straight from emmeans and the second manually plotting back to baseline.


library(simstudy)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)

# Simulate longitudinal data
var <- 5.5^2
tdef <- defData(varname = "group", dist = "binary", formula = 0.5)
tdef <- defData(tdef, varname = "Y0", dist = "normal", formula = 30, variance = 5.5^2)
tdef <- defData(tdef, varname = "Y1", dist = "normal", formula = "Y0 - 5 - 5 * group", variance = var) # decrease both groups by 5 from baseline and a further 5 for group = 1
tdef <- defData(tdef, varname = "Y2", dist = "normal", formula = "Y0 - 10 - 7.5 * group", variance = var) # decrease both groups by 10 from baseline and a further 7.5 for group = 1
tdef <- defData(tdef, varname = "Y3", dist = "normal", formula = "Y0 - 15 - 10 * group", variance = var) # decrease both groups by 15 from baseline and a further 10 for group = 1

# Generate for desired n
set.seed(85748477)
dtTrial <- genData(60, tdef)
head(dtTrial)
dtTrial <- addPeriods(dtTrial, nPeriods = 4, idvars = "id", timevars = c("Y0", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3"), timevarName = "Y")
dtTrial <- dtTrial |> 
  arrange(id)
head(dtTrial, 20)

# Pull out baseline
dtTime <- dtTrial |> 
  rename(time = period)
dtTime$time <- factor(dtTime$time)
dtTime$timeID <- NULL
dtTime <- dtTime |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(base = first(Y))
dtTime <- dtTime |> 
  filter(time != 0)
head(dtTime, 20)

# Calculate change scores
dtTime$change <- dtTime$Y - dtTime$base
head(dtTime, 20)

# Mixed-model
mod <- lmer(change ~ group*time + base + (1|id), data = dtTime)

# Emmeans - plots from first time point after baseline (as expected)
mod_emm <- emmeans(mod, ~ group + time)
emmip(mod, group ~ time, CIs = T) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Emmean") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-30,0), breaks = seq(-30,0, by = 5))

# But we want a plot that includes the baseline score and for a change outcome, the baseline will be 0. So, instead of using emmip, construct the plot using ggplot.
mod_emm <- mod_emm |> 
  data.frame() |> 
  select(group, time, emmean, lower.CL, upper.CL)
# Create two additional rows for emmeans change = 0 at baseline
mod_emm <- rbind(expand.grid(group = c(0,1), time = 0, emmean = 0, lower.CL = 0, upper.CL = 0), mod_emm)
mod_emm$group <- factor(mod_emm$group)
mod_emm$time <- as.numeric(mod_emm$time)

# Plot
ggplot(mod_emm, aes(time, emmean)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = group), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(color = group), linewidth = 0.8) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = upper.CL, ymin = lower.CL, color = group), width = 0.1) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Emmean") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-30,0), breaks = seq(-30,0, by = 5))


Can you add a plot of the adjusted means and describe a bit more what that is? I think this is a disciplinary thing that many not be familiar with.
